# easyautocomplete: is that possible to pass an array to getValue method?

Tags: json, easyautocomplete

For example, i want to search the word in "name" and "code" fields at the same time. How can i do that?
Maybe something like: 
getValue: "name", "code",

```js
var options = {
 url: "http://easyautocomplete.com/resources/countries.json",

 getValue: "name",

 list: {
  match: {
   enabled: true
  }
 }
};

$("#provider").easyAutocomplete(options);
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Test</title>

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="provider"/>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://easyautocomplete.com/dist/jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can advice another solution too

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass a function to the getValue option, like so:

```
     getValue: function(element) {
         var my_value = element.name + ' ' + element.code;
         return my_value;
     },
```

See their [docs](http://easyautocomplete.com/guide) for more information.